# Is it possible to get geoJSON data for all zipcodes in Malaga Spain?

Tags: geospatial

Trying to use mapbox to create polygons outlining all zipcodes in Malaga. Mapbox requires geoJSON data in order to draw the polygon around the zipcode boundaries. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OSM data, for example overpass query: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1wRz